# how to block the fields of a formbuilder in symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, twig, formbuilder

By the way I would like to modify the fields of an admin, starting from the fact that an admin is a user.

But I want the admin to modify only certain fields and not all the fields that a user can have. I want the admin to change only his username, his password and his tel number.

But when I display all fields appear, even those that are not desired.
Here is my formbuilder:

```
<?php

namespace Doctix\AdminBundle\Form;


use Doctix\UserBundle\Form\UserType;
use Doctix\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TelType;
   class AdminType extends AbstractType
  {
   /**
   * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
   * @param array $options
   */
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder->add('user', UserType::class);

  }

   /**
   * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
   */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
         'data_class' => 'Doctix\AdminBundle\Entity\Admin'
       ));
   }
      }
```

And my view:

```
   <div class="box_general padding_bottom">

               {{ form_start(form,{'attr': {'id': 'form1'}}) }}


               {% if form.user.username is defined %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            {{ form_widget(form.user.username, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Email'}}) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if form.user.password is defined %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-md-5 control-label">Mot de passe</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            {{ form_widget(form.user.password, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Password'}}) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                   {% if form.user.numTel is defined %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-md-5 control-label">N° Téléphone</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            {{ form_widget(form.user.numTel, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'N° Téléphone'}}) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}

                          {{ form_end(form) }}
                </div>


                 <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" form="form1"> Valider</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <a  href="{{ path('doctix_admin_users_parametre') }}" class=" btn btn-danger btn-lg">Annuler </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And here is the picture of my display :
      
[rendering of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaedF.jpg)

On the picture, I only want the first 3 lines, and not the following at the bottom. And that the change at the click validate takes effect.

Finally my controller:

```
 public function editprofilAction(Request $request){
       $user = $this->getUser();
    if($user===null){
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Utilisateur Inexistant');
    }

    else {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('DoctixAdminBundle:Admin');
        $admin = $repo->findOneBy(array(
            'user' => $user,
        ));
        $form = $this->createForm('Doctix\AdminBundle\Form\AdminType', $admin);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $admin->getUser()->setSalt('');
            $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($admin->getUser());
            $password_encoder = $encoder->encodePassword($admin->getUser()->getPassword(), $admin->getUser()->getSalt());
            $admin->getUser()->setPassword($password_encoder);
            $admin->getUser()->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
            $em->flush();
            // creation d'un flash bag pour une notification flash
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('Notice', 'Profil Modifié avec succés');
            // redirection
            $url = $this->generateUrl('doctix_admin_users_parametre');
            // redirection permanente avec le status http 301 ::)))))
            return $this->redirect($url,301);

        }else{
            return $this->render('DoctixAdminBundle:User:editprofil.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
        }


    }

 }
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

By default Twig `form_end()` function renders all remaining fields when called. You can also avoid this setting `render_rest` option as `false`

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

However if `UserType::class` defines some constraints on other fields that are not rendered, form validation might fail when you call `$form->isValid()`. In that case you should consider a manual validation in your controller.

If you keep current Twig implementation then you also have to explicitly load the CSRF token (active by default for every form) by calling `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}` in your template.

Comment: Thanks @DrKey, it's works, but when I click on validate, the change is not made. Can u help me. Thanks

Comment: @MohamedSacko do you have any error when you submit the form? Did you check if validation works and if `$em->flush()` is then called?

Comment: yes $em->flush () is called, but validation is not done because symfony tells me that the CSRF token is invalid. Please return the form.

Comment: where should this {{form_widget (form._token)}} be placed?

Comment: should I use it for each form in my template ?